# DIVs don't line up

Tags: html, css

I have created a jsfiddle for you to see what I'm doing.

https://jsfiddle.net/pksml/3mp1Lnw8/5/

```
#page-wrapper {
margin-left: 205px;
background-color: green;
}
```

The menu wrapper (orange) and the page wrapper (green) should both be at the top of the content wrapper (blue). But the green block looks to have a top margin (which it doesn't).

My question is this: why don't the orange and green blocks both line up at the top of the blue block?

Is some of my CSS code wrong? Thanks for your input!

Comment: If I remove the 'overflow: auto; height: auto', the blocks will line up, but the blue parent box shrinks to a height of 0px. That's a problem too...

Comment: you want to make a grid?

Comment: `div` tag has default style **display: block** and you also have margin-left on the page wrapper.. see update fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3mp1Lnw8/7/ , I just remove the margin-left and added a p tag also in the *menu wrapper*

Comment: @mmativ I am thinking about the possibility of a grid, but I'm not sure yet. What I needed was for the green block to expand to fill the maximum width of its container (because it will hold multiple columns). Turns out afelixj figured out my silly little "problem" with the paragraph tag.

Comment: My end goal is for the menu to disappear and be a clickable link below 600px. I just needed this little snafu cleared up first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the default `margin` of `p` tag which is pushing the green `div` down.

```css
HTML {
  background: #cccccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

#bounding-wrapper {
  min-width: 320px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

#content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
  height: auto !important;
  background-color: blue;
}

#menu-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
  float: left;
}

#page-wrapper {
  margin-left: 205px;
  background-color: green;
}
  p{
margin: 0 0 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="bounding-wrapper">
  <div id="content-wrapper">
<div id="menu-wrapper">
  this is in the menu wrapper
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga dolores voluptatibus itaque dolor quod.</p>
</div>
<!-- menu wrapper -->
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <p>this is in the page wrapper</p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum repellendus eum delectus deserunt molestiae cum, 
</div>
<!-- page wrapper -->
  </div>
  <!-- content wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- bounding wrapper -->
```

Comment: Thanks @afelixj! You completely understood my question! I'm glad the answer was so simple. That leads me to another question: why doesn't the div's background surround the margins of the paragraph inside the div?

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io/craigiswayne/pen/mPxJqv

** Makes use of flex box **

**CSS:**

```
.block{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#8BC34A;
}

.block.fill{
  background-color:#F44336;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
}

.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The one thing I still need is for the green box to have its width go to the right edge of its parent div.

Answer (score 1):

You need to float both `menu-wrapper` and `page-wrapper`.

Looks like from your addition of the right margin you are trying to position the left menu? If so you could do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/jgoley/98abyyp2/

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mp1Lnw8/8/)

```
#page-wrapper {
   float:left;
   background-color: green;
}
```

use float:left instead of marigin left

Answer (score 1):

I think the code below should work for you!

All I added was `display: inline-block;` to `#menu-wrapper` and `#page-wrapper`.

All I removed was the `float: left;` from `#menu-wrapper` and `margin-left: 205;` from `#page-wrapper`.

---

```css
 HTML {
   background: #cccccc;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 
 *,
 *:before,
 *:after {
   box-sizing: inherit;
 }
 
 #bounding-wrapper {
   min-width: 320px;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 10px;
 }
 
 #content-wrapper {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   overflow: auto;
   height: auto !important;
   background-color: blue;
 }
 
 #menu-wrapper {
   width: 200px;
   background-color: orange;
   display: inline-block;
 }
 
 #page-wrapper {
   background-color: green;
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<div id="bounding-wrapper">
  <div id="content-wrapper">
    <div id="menu-wrapper">
      this is in the menu wrapper
    </div>
    <!-- menu wrapper -->
    <div id="page-wrapper">
      <p>this is in the page wrapper</p>
    </div>
    <!-- page wrapper -->
  </div>
  <!-- content wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- bounding wrapper -->
```

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 1):

you have two solutions,

1. you can set the `display` property of the `#page-wrapper` to be
   `display:inline-block`
2. if you don't want to change its `display` property for any reason so
   you can add `float:left` to the `#page-wrapper` as well

then no need for `margin-left:205px` in `#page-wrapper`